# Passing a variable to an aspect

Tags: java, spring, aop, statsd

I'm trying to measure metrics in my code using a combination of AOP and statsd. Particularly, I'd like a developer to be able to create a timer by just adding an annotation to the method, and specifying its name and tags, as below:

```
@Timed(name="executeHistoryDataSet", tags={dataSetInfo.getLabel()})
@Override
public String executeHistoryDataSet(DataSet dataSetInfo) throws DataServiceException {
    String results = executeDataSet(dataSetInfo);
    return results;
}
```

This would include information about the arguments as tags.  However, this is displaying an `attribute value must be constant` error, because the arguments of annotations must not be variable, which `dataSetInfo.getLabel()` definitely isn't.

It is desirable that a developer would be able to create a new timer without creating a new aspect and advice(`@Timed` would be the annotation for all timers), so is there any way that I could have this functionality, where I pass something like `tags` to the advice, but this can be not constant and differ from method to method?

---

Here is the annotation itself:

```
public @interface Timed {
    String name();
    String[] tags();
}
```

And its aspect:

```
@Aspect
public class MetricsAspects {

    private static final StatsDClient statsd = new NonBlockingStatsDClient(
        "my.prefix",                    //prefix to any stats
        "statsd-host",                  //often "localhost"
        8125,                           //port
        "tag", "another tag"            //tags always applied to stats
    );

    @Around ("execution(* *(..) && @annotation(timed)")
    public Object timeAround(ProceedingJoinPoint point, Timed timed) throws Throwable {

        String metricName = timed.name();
        String[] metricTags = timed.tags();
        long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
        Object result = point.proceed();
        long duration = System.currentTimeMillis() - start;
        statsd.recordExecutionTime(metricName, duration, metricTags);
        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: The error is slightly misleading. Annotation member values need to either be constant expressions, class literals, or enum constants.

Answer (score 0):

A annotation needs to have its arguments known at compile time. Since at compile time it is unknown which `Dataset` object is given to this function whenever it is executed, the compiler throws the error.